# Верстка сложных интерфейсов без css

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, веб-дизайн

Существует ли возможность верстать очень сложные интерфейсы без привлечения css? Если такая возможность существует и не одна, то какая лучшая?

Если не понятно о чем я, то хочется следующее -

1. чтобы размещение объектов было, как на плоскости, то есть работать с
2. чтобы это была очень легкая библиотека или фраймворк, который можно
   было бы сочетать с другими фраймворками.
3. не jQuery
4. Мультиплатформено и мультибраузерно.
5. работало чтобы без лаг.

Comment: что именно вы подразумеваете под "без CSS"? без ручного написания CSS? CSS - это **единственный** способ управления расположением элементов, если учитывать, что аттрибуты style в html - это тоже css.

Comment: @PashaPash: Вы хотите сказать, что css - это то, файл с расширением css, который я загружаю?

Comment: CSS это не только файл. CSS - это упоминание практически любого свойства элемента в разметке.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что я не знаю о существовании препроцессоров? Прочитайте мой первый коммент - я же там открытым текстом спросил вас - вам вообще без CSS (т.е. даже препроцессор вас не устроит). или без ручного написания CSS (сказали бы да - я бы посоветовал вам LESS/SASS). Не минусовал (-5 - не мои), не писал ответ "Вы вообще понимаете что спросили?", а буквально спросил - вам нужен препроцессор или вообще чистый HTML? Странно, но я в этом вопросе был *единственным*, кто пытался вам как-то помочь. Удачи вам с таким отношением к людям, которые стараются вам помочь :)

Comment: @shatal, давайте обойдемся без личных выпадов и оскорблений.

Comment: @shatal true story, PashaPash не смог бы один наставить шесть минусов. Зря вы его так оскорбляете. Он очень многим новичкам помогает и всегда не просто закрывает, а задает уточняющие вопросы и помогает освоиться.

Comment: @PashaPash: буквально Вы человеку делавшему первые шаги сказали следующее - CSS - это единственный способ управления расположением элементов, если учитывать, что аттрибуты style в html - это тоже css.  Где Вы тут БУКВАЛЬНО спросили что мне нужен препроцессор? Ваш ответ не больше не меньше затрагивает лишь Ваше самолюбие из-за которого Вы поставили своими словами жирную точку - без css нельзя сделать то, о чем я спрашивал. А именно.. можете ещё раз посмотреть что я спрашивал.

Comment: @PashaPash: хотите посмотреть на себя со стороны? Вот ответ который я дал в Вашем стиле (первый коммент, надеюсь Вы успеете его посмотреть). И заметь я там прямо и буквально указал ответ... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477192/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-jquery-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: @shatal еще раз - "Вы вообще понимаете что спросили" написал не я. Это написал аноним (на самом деле TheDoctor).  Можете считать что это лично я вас заминусовал и закрыл. На самом деле я просто оставил нейтральный уточняющий комментарий. Извините, если он вызвал у вас такую негативную реакцию :(

Answer (score 5):

Вы вообще понимаете что спросили?
CSS - это вся суть отображения, для наглядности:

[image: Так выглядит этот вопрос без стилей]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это не самый сложный интерфейс.
А JS в любом случае будет обращаться к CSS для отображения. Всякие jQuery и другие библиотеки анимируют именно благодаря CSS.
Без него никак.
Есть парочка свойств для HTML-парсера, но это мало что меняет.
Если сложный интерфейс может быть как на первой картинке, то ответ на вопрос - да, можно сверстать без CSS.
Иначе - забудь.

Comment: Вы наверное меня не поняли. Я хочу объекты-html расставлять будто бы они находятся на плоскости. Я хочу как на canvas или flash расставлять элементы. Есть что-то для этого?

Comment: хотя наверное можно... Эх.. нельзя..  
Хотел сказать что можно же использовать матрицу от самого css, но ведь css статичный язык, у меня же не получится задать значение как свойство, которое я пом могу при желании изменить. Типа у Вас элемент будет в двое больше, от точки A до B 100 px, а у меня из-за меньшего монитора 50. Понимаете о чем я?

Comment: А предположим сложный тач-скролл я вообще не смогу сделать на css. На js я его за час напишу, не разу не делав, а css мне придется несколько лет учится.

Comment: @shatal, Хм, так они и так на плоскости, точнее на слое, так они называются.
Как в canvas - рисуй в канвасе, правда сложный интерфейс в канвасе не рисуют.
Разница в мониторах - один из главных камней преткновения любого верстальщика. Именно из-за этого придумали всякие там адаптивные вёрстки, относительные единицы измерения и пр. И ещё из-за IE :)

Comment: @shatal, Ты, видимо, путаешь слон с сосиской - CSS и не должен отвечать за функционал, это дело JS. И JS не должен парится как отображается приложение - это дело CSS. О модели MVC слышал?

Comment: Слышал, но Вас не понимаю. Вы говорите что js не отвечает за то, как отображается представление, а я под этими словами понимаю - что если кто-то делает анимацию или интерактив на js тот вообще не программист, ведь Вы говорите, что так быть не должно. Возможно я.. А что я? Вы же прямо так написал, я ничего не придумал. А ещё Вы говорите, что js, который является языком созданным специально для представления, не должен заботится о отображении. и аргументируете все это безумие словами, которые вообще тут неуместны, ведь говоря о html, css, js не подразумевают m или c.

Comment: @shatal, Вынос мозга. JS делает расчёты, взаимодействует с пользователем и/или другими БД, **задаёт CSS**, но браузер отображает элементы основываясь именно на CSS, JS лишь может установить стиль, но правила отображения именно через CSS идут.

Comment: вынос от Вами же сказанных слов? Повторю, что не я сказал, что js безразлично, как отображаются элементы. js создан для этих самых элементов и именно он заботится и переживает за них. Если бы елементам не нужен был бы js, то js вообще бы был ненужен. И Вам не кажется, что браузер основывается на значении свойств, которые можно задать, как через js, так и через сss? Правила отображения через css? Это что значит, что я не могу через js поменять координаты элемента? Или Вы подразумеваете под словом "правило" - "так делают все"?  И не нужно умничать не получается!