# Как в Jquery назначить css свойство из атрибута?

Tags: jquery

Есть список элементов

```
<li>
    <label  data-bg="#d6eff3" ></label>
</li>
<li>
    <label  data-bg="#fff" ></label>
</li>
<li>
    <label  data-bg="#ff0000" ></label>
</li>
```

Как сделать, чтобы их background подгружался сразу из атрибута `data-bg`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Если я правильно понял, то таким образом:

```js
$('#list li').each(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data('bg'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li data-bg="blue">1</li>
  <li data-bg="red">2</li>
  <li data-bg="green">3</li>
</ul>
```

Проходим по всем пунктам списка, используя [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), вытаскиваем значение `data-bg` и собственно стилизуем.

**Обновлено**
У Вас отредактировали вопрос, новые моменты открылись, но принцип это не меняет. Перебирать только надо в вашем случаи `label`, и если требуется задать фон именно тегу `li`, то воспользоваться [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('#list li label').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().css("background-color", $(this).data('bg'));
})
```

Comment: вместо each можно использовать [перегрузку функции css которая принимает вторым параметром функцию](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function), например так: `$('#list li').css("background-color", function(){ return this.find('label').data('bg')})`

Comment: @Grundy Да, красиво. ) только видимо `this.find` = `$(this).find`

Comment: да, _this.find = $(this).find_, _this_ как и во всех остальных коллбеках указывает на сам HTML элемент